# Surface plot from txt file in python

Tags: python, plot, surface

What is the simplest way to create a surface plot from a `.txt` file with data points arranged in, say `N` rows and `M` columns? I just want to see what the file looks when layed onto a plane with each data point representing the height of the surface at that point, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can read the file into a matrix, you can use most popular plotting libraries to create a contour plot. (Contour is the 2D equivalent of surface, which is 3D).

Examples here:  https://plot.ly/python/contour-plots/